# same formula but different result in Matlab and Excel

Tags: excel, matlab

I have one formula:

```
800/(0.3*F6)*((20/SQRT(3.14*E6*A6^3))*EXP(-(40-F6*A6)^2/4*F6*A6))
A6 = 1
E6 = 1
F6 = 1
```

The answer in Excel is 4.1592E+169, but Matlab report the answer is 2.1780e-161.

Do I miss something here?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend splitting apart this lengthy expression into smaller calculations, and then combine them at the end.  Do this in both Excel and Matlab and you'll be able to more easily diagnose why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is due to the operator precedence in Excel, where `-2^2 = (-2)^2 = 4`, whereas `-2^2 = -(2^2) = -4` in MATLAB.

Hence `-(40-F6*A6)^2` in Excel is `(-(40-F6*A6))^2`, in MATLAB it is `-((40-F6*A6)^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations in MATLAB is different. MATLAB evaluates as if you have extra parenthesis in the Excel formula:

Excel: `EXP(-(40-F6*A6)^2/4*F6*A6))`

Excel to match MATLAB: `EXP(-((40-F6*A6)^2/4*F6*A6)))`

MATLAB to match Excel: `exp((-(40-F6*A6))^2/4*F6*A6)`

That is, [MATLAB's operator precendence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html) has `mpower` (`^`) as higher than everything but parenthesis. Thus, it will perform the `^` operation *before the negation*, unless you put in parenthesis.